# Trying to get Macro to automatically adjust DataRange for Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm sorry if this is basic but I can't seem to figure this out .
Long story short my file has several tabs with lot's of data and each tab has a pivot table.  What I need is a Macro that adjusts the data range of the Pivot table to the data in current sheet.  I have it now set with a bigger range giving me Blanks which drives me nuts.

Here is my code :

```
    Dim Data_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Pivot_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim StartPoint As Range
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim PivotName As String
Dim NewRange As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

'Set Pivot Table & Source Worksheet
Set Data_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1")
Set Pivot_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1")

'Enter in Pivot Table Name
PivotName = "PivotTable1"

'Defining Staring Point & Dynamic Range
Data_Sheet.Activate
Set StartPoint = Data_Sheet.Range("V2")
LastCol = StartPoint.End(xlToRight).Column
DownCell = StartPoint.End(xlDown).Row
Set DataRange = Data_Sheet.Range(StartPoint, Cells(DownCell, LastCol))
NewRange = Data_Sheet.Name & "!" & DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange _
    , Version:=6)
```

Now when I try this I get the "Run time error -2147024809" error stating that The pivottable name is invalid .

Comment: If the sheet has only one pivot table try `ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1),ChangePivotCache`

Comment: Put your data in a table (Ctrl + T to create table) and point the pivot table at that - it will update on Refresh as you add/remove data.

Comment: I've tried "ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1),ChangePivotCache" but seem to get the same error.
As far as pointing the pivot table at a table I've tried but seems to crash and cause issues having the data in a table with other existing Macros that import data from other Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

This updates all the sheets that have 1 pivot table

```vb
Sub Update()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, newrange As String
   
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
       With ws
          If .PivotTables.Count = 1 Then
              Set cell = .Range("V2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)
              Set rng = .Range("V2", cell)
              newrange = "'" & ws.Name & "'!" & rng.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
              
              .PivotTables(1).ChangePivotCache _
                 wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                 SourceData:=newrange, Version:=6)
           End If
       End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply just tried this and still getting a run time error

Comment: @kwen pivottable name is invalid . ?

Comment: My apologies its not the same run time error.  It's giving me a different one stating "The pivottable field name is not valid"

Comment: @kwen I just notice your data starts in V2 not A2 so `Set rng = .Range("A2").CurrentRegion` is incorrect. Use your code to set the range.

Comment: I forgot to mention this but yes I changed it to V2 before implementing the macro

Comment: @kwen see update

Comment: Tried this and still getting the "The pivottable field name us not valid"  .  I've gone ahead and made sure all pivot tables on each sheet are named "1"

Comment: @kwen its not the pivot table name it is field name . is it one particular sheet or all of them.? After `newrange = ` add `msgbox newrange` and check the range is as expected.

Comment: The message box is giving me '1'!R2C22:R5000c45

Comment: I've tried on all sheets that have different data amounts and always same message box

Comment: @kwen that is `V2:AS5000` is that correct range forthe  data ?

Comment: That is the current range that it is set at but the data is only range v2 : as1350

Comment: @kwen It's odd that the `.End(xlDown)` is finding cell AS5000 if the data only goes to AS1350. What is in the range AS1351 to AS5000 ?

Comment: Empty cells.  Now when I first set the range in order to capture everything I set the range to 5000 as the data can go upwards to low 4000s

Comment: @kwen If you manually select V2 and then Cntl right , ctrl down does it go to AS5000 ?

Comment: It does.  However if I do ctrl shit right and down only gies to 386 which is where the data ends

Comment: Well figured it out.  Seems there was "something" in cell AJ2 making the selection wrong giving all the errors. So the formula works perfect thanks again CDP1802